# how can I jail user in a directory in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, user, vsftpd, chroot-jail

I have installed vsftpd in ubuntu. I have created a user in name of ftpadmin by command

```
sudo useradd ftpadmin
```

and I have set its password too, I also have created a home directory for it using

```
sudo mkdir /home/ftp.
```

My problem is this user can access and see others directories which I don't want. I want ftpadmin can access only to it's own directory. I have tried to make a directory in var/www too but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any homework at all ?

First page of a Google search leads to the solution -
Set 
chroot_local_user=yes
in /etc/fsftpd/vsftpd.conf

Comment: thanka you alot. one more thing now my ftpadmin don't have access to write anything in its directory.it is the owner with 770 permission but it cant write anything